# Mybatis Batch Select Query - Java

Tags: java, mysql, spring, batch-processing, mybatis

I want to fetch all the records from a table while satisfying certain conditions in mybatis select query. 
As an example:

```
SELECT * FROM Employee e WHERE e.location = ? AND e.status = ?
```

Set of parameters are passes as a List of Maps to generate multiple queries as follows.

```
List = {{location=Colombo, status=available}, {location=Galle, status=onCall}}

SELECT * FROM Employee e WHERE e.location = 'Colombo' AND e.status = 'available' 
SELECT * FROM Employee e WHERE e.location = 'Galle' AND e.status = 'onCall'
```

What I want to do is running the above queries in batch mode.

Here what I tried but the query is not as expected.

```
<select id="availabeEmployees" parameterType="java.util.List"
        resultMap="employeeDtoMap">
    SELECT * FROM Employee e
    WHERE
    <foreach item="item" index="index" collection="list">
        e.location = #{item.location}
        AND e.status = #{item.status}
    </foreach>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with the following solution. I have used UNION to combined all the select queries. Add a little tricky solution to avoid appending UNION to the last select query. Set the `last == true` for last element of the map and `false` for others.

```
<select id="availabeEmployees" parameterType="java.util.List"
        resultMap="employeeDtoMap">
    <foreach item="item" index="index" collection="list">
        SELECT * FROM Employee e
        WHERE e.location = #{item.location}
        AND e.status = #{item.status}
        <if test="item.last == 'false'">UNION</if>
    </foreach>
</select>
```

Comment: You don't need that tricky solution to separate queries with `UNION`. Just add `separator="UNION"` in `<foreach ...` and it will do the trick.